# The column i am trying to format does exist but the system is showing error that it is missing

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

I am cleaning a csv file that has stock prices data of big companies, it has a column named "Date", checked it in excel, even printed the head of the column etc. THE COLUMN EXISTS. However, while running the code this error is continuously showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cvalley\Documents\Python Scripts\Project 1.py", line 21, in <module>
    data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format=date_format)
                                  ~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\cvalley\anaconda3\envs\testenv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\cvalley\anaconda3\envs\testenv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3655, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Date'
```

consulted with chatgpt and blackbox AI but of no avail. Please help

I have tried debugging it changing the code several times but the error still persists. The date column exists but the error still shows up that the date column does not exist.

Comment: Print `data.columns`. Are there spaces yet unaccounted for?

Comment: there is white space in your column name, check that out.

Comment: Check data in csv with text editor (Notepad, Sumblime Text...) instead of Excel.

Comment: there are no whitespaces in the column names the error is still there